# Booting into twrp unsuccessful

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, boot, twrp

Followed the steps mentioned in
http://www.droidape.com/install-twrp-and-root-moto-g-2014-2nd-generation/

installed twrp successfully. But as  I try to get into the recovery the screen shows the android guy lying on its back(no command). Please help

Comment: After step 6,  boot into recovery using the options on your phone and from there boot into system. This may be the problem as stock recovery replaces custom recovery of you directly boot into system after flashing custom recovery

Comment: For more details see this, though the phone is different, principle is samehttps://twrp.me/devices/lgnexus5.html

Comment: Also,When TWRP starts up for the first time, you'll see a menu saying "Swipe to allow modifications or keep read only." Make sure to swipe the slider at the bottom of the screen here to make TWRP your permanent recovery, source http://nexus5.wonderhowto.com/forum/install-custom-recovery-your-nexus-device-without-rooting-0159035/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moto devices with a stock ROM have a facility to replace the recovery with the stock image, TWRP handles this but you have to reboot into recovery once before starting the phone normally. Flash TWRP with fastboot and boot into it, allow changes (or first, say No, then do a backup!) then within TWRP do a Reboot -> Recovery, this will "set" the recovery so it will not be replaced.

`fastboot boot twrp.img` (replace *twrp.img* with the actual filename for your TWRP image)

TWRP should load. Do not allow changes and perform a full backup (keep this safe so you can restore to known good point if needed at some time). Once this is done, go to Home - Reboot - Bootloader

Flash TWRP with `fastboot flash recovery twrp.img` and then reboot into the bootloader with `fastboot reboot-bootloader` and start Recovery, TWRP should start.

In TWRP, allow changes and go to Reboot and select Recovery, the device should reboot and TWRP will start again. Select the option to allow changes, go to Reboot and select Recovery, this will "set" TWRP as the static recovery image.

You can now Reboot - System and the phone should start with TWRP left in place.

Comment: @NilabhraPatra Glad it worked for you, if this answer is acceptable, please mark it as the Accepted Answer, and upvote it if you like. That is how Q&A works here.