# Unable to Downgrade after upgrade to Android M from Android L

Tags: rooting, android-versions

I upgraded my **MOTO G 3rd Gen (XT1550)** to **Android M**. After that I tried to **root** My Phone but unable to Root **Android M.** So I decided to Downgrade to **Android L**. But also unable to Downgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for Downgrading **MOTO G 3rd Gen (XT1550) Android M to Android L**

---

1) Extract the folder *.zip

2) Enter in the Extracted folder.

3) If "fastboot" not installed

Then you can download it from here [Download Fastboot](https://redirect.viglink.com/?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_151841922035615&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&libId=jdjvl5bk01000n4o000DL3c7ci40u&loc=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D2588979&v=1&out=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dropbox.com%2Fs%2Fmcxw0yy3jvydupd%2Fadb-setup-1.4.3.exe%3Fdl%3D0&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F&title=%5BOFFICIAL%5D%5BTOOL%5D%5BWINDOWS%5D%20ADB%2C%20Fastboot%20and%20%E2%80%A6%20%7C%20Android%20Development%20and%20Hacking&txt=Dropbox)

4)  Test fastboot by typing: fastboot devices
     You should see:

```
<serial number> fastboot
```

5) You are now ready to flash the fastboot files

Fastboot Commands:

```
"Do commands manually, one at a time - checking that each one returns an [OKAY]."
```

***NOTE: system.img_sparsechunks may differ in number + name - Always check contents of folder you're working with.***

```
fastboot oem fb_mode_set
```

If you want to Downgrade from Android M to Android L the **Don't flash gpt.bin**

> **fastboot flash partition gpt.bin <---- Don't Do this Step**

```
fastboot flash bootloader bootloader.img

fastboot flash logo logo.bin

fastboot flash boot boot.img

fastboot flash recovery recovery.img

fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.0

fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.1

fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.2

fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.3

fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.4

fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin

fastboot erase modemst1

fastboot erase modemst2

fastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn

fastboot erase cache

fastboot erase userdata

fastboot erase customize

fastboot erase clogo

fastboot oem fb_mode_clear

fastboot reboot
```

---

**For Rooting MOTO G 3rd Gen (XT1550) Android M**

---

1) Flash(Permanent) or Boot(Temporary) with TWRP

You can download TWRP from Here [Download TWRP](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sf9pvzbtc8j9k9e/recovery.img?dl=0)

- Flashing TWRP

  ```
    fastboot flash recovery {TWRP File's Name with extension}
  ```
- Booting TWRP

  ```
    fastboot boot {TWRP File's Name with extension}
  ```

2) Restart the phone in recovery mode **(If flashed)** <---- Those who use booted using TWRP Skip this step

3) Using TWRP flash the SuperSU

You can download SuperSU from Here [Download SuperSU](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uh6st9c1sr6frhm/BETA-SuperSU-v2.62-3-20151211162651.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the exchange of comments in other answer and the link provided, the problem is with SuperSu:

Version 2.62 ( from memory) is normal SuperSu

Version 2.76 is *system less root*, which provides root without modifying system partition. My device is rooted with this and I had the same problem.

Systemless root requires different treatment.

First thing to do is shut the device by `adb shell reboot -p` . Next is to boot into recovery, enter TWRP terminal and key `''echo SYSTEMLESS=true>>/data/.supersu''` without quotes ( I had read of this in [this XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-x-play/general/root-how-to-root-6-0-easly-t3277202/page15)

After this reboot into recovery for custom recovery to replace stock. Else in some current devices the custom recovery is replaced by stock. See this for more [Booting into twrp unsuccessful](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/150211/131553)

Comment: +1: obviously you have _much_ more hands-on experience with systemless stuff. I have CM on nearly all devices and system-mode SuperSU on others (yes I deliberately avoided systemless).

Comment: @Andy Yan: Thanks. Not really. Not conversant at all with adb commands, so was referring to you for corrections. It was from hastily made notes when i got into the mess of systemless SU without knowing the complications ( accidentally deleted my earlier comment)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to downgrade, just get your phone rooted.

Phones like Moto G can be rooted as easily as unlocking the bootloader, flashing a custom recovery via fastboot and flashing SuperSU through it. If you're using one-click rooters then just give them up.

Comment: I tried flashing custom recovery and SuperSu but unable to Root. I tried it atleast 5-6  times.

Comment: @beast_f5 What's the syndrome? Did the SuperSU app appear at all after flashing?

Comment: After flashing supersu it goes to bootloop

Comment: @beast_f5 Sounds like the SuperSU version is too low... Get 2.76 if you haven't.

Comment: I tried with version 2.76. But my bad

Comment: Seeing this [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/2015-moto-g/general/guide-install-twrp-root-xposed-t3294588) using exactly the same steps as I gave, I'm out of clues as of now. If you're currently in a hurry to use the phone, back up data from recovery and get phone back to working state first by flashing a stock firmware.

Comment: @AndyYan: please have a look at my answer and suggest corrections if need be. Let's crack this